# JS - Random Array item excluding value already given

Tags: javascript, function, random, position, rectangles

need to find a solution for this.

I have 3 objects Located on screen at position: Object1 -0.7, Object2 0, Object3 -0.7.

Now I want to call the position random so every time I call the function the 3 objects have different X location WITHOUT OVERLAPPING.

So far I have:

```
    var rectPos = [ -0.7, 0, 0.7 ];
    var rand1 = rectPos[Math.floor(Math.random() * rectPos.length)];
    var rand2 = rectPos[Math.floor(Math.random() * rectPos.length)];
    var rand3 = rectPos[Math.floor(Math.random() * rectPos.length)];

rect1 = rand1;
rect2 = rand2;
rect3 = rand3;
```

but I cannot figure out how to not get the object overleaping.

any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several solutions. You can shuffle the array and then pick the first value for the first rectangle, the second value for the second rectangle etc. Other approach can be to remove selected value from the array after it has been 'chosen'. The following samples should work for any size of arrays.

1 Simple Shuffle by random sort (note you can use [Fisher Yates Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for better randomization :? )

```
var arr = [-0.7, 0, 0.7];

arr.sort(function(){
    return Math.random() - Math.random();
});

// rect1 = arr[0] 
// rect2 = arr[1] ... etc.
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/boj6evtk/8/)

2 Remove the randomized from the array

```
var arr = [-0.7, 0, 0.7];

var copy = arr.slice(0); // Copy the initial array
var rects = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1){
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    rects.push(copy[index]);
    copy.splice(index, 1); // Remove the 'chosen' value from the copied array
}

// rect1 = rects[0] 
// rect2 = rects[1] ... etc.
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/boj6evtk/4/)

3 Others Like randoming while randomed value is not unique .. [No demo]

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?:

```
var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * rectPos.length);
```

@Edit:

```
var test = [-0.7, 0, 0.7];

function getPosition() {
  var rectPos = test.slice(); ;
  function getX(index) {
    var res = rectPos[index];
    rectPos.splice(index, 1);
    return res
  }
  var rand1 = getX(Math.floor(Math.random() * rectPos.length));
  var rand2 = getX(Math.floor(Math.random() * rectPos.length));
  var rand3 = getX(Math.floor(Math.random() * rectPos.length));
}
```

Comment: nope because is not giving me the specified values I need (-0.7, 0, 0.7). Each object need to have one of these values randomly avoiding to get the same value for each objects

Comment: I think I have the answer but I don't know if it is optimal.

Comment: You need to `return` rand1 ,rand2 ,rand3. I forget about it.